# how many samples do i need to collect for my research work in order to study mother tongue influence on English pronunciation?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

I am doing research on the topic 'mother tongue influence on English pronunciation'. the speakers that I have selected belongs to a particular region of my country. their mother tongue is not English but they know the language to a fair amount because they have studied English as a second language in their schools and colleges. I am a bit confused as I don't know how many speakers' recordings should I collect as samples for analysing their speech pattern and pronunciation. up till now I have collected 15 recordings as samples. is this much enough or should I collect more?

Comment: Sample size design depends on what exactly you're going to do, e.g. what margin of error at what level of confidence you want. Do you have any more details?

Comment: @WavesWashSands thanks for replying. speakers that i have chosen has hindi as thier mother tongue and english is their second language. i gave them a list of words and some sentence to read. i noticed that they there is a lot of deviation in their pronunciation. they were unable to articulate many diphthongs, they were unable to make out difference between s, sh, and z sounds, etc. the model variety that i have taken as reference is R.P

Comment: The English learned in India may be Indian English, which is a dialect of English with many speakers.  Native Hindi speakers may have learned Indian English perfectly, even though their speech differs a lot from the dialects in Britain or the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is that you need 5 examples to make a particular point. So if you want to say something about about [i] pronounced by speaker AM, and how it is different from [e], then you need 5 examples of each vowel in a comparable context, thus 10 from AM. Let's say you are looking at F1 in vowels (a standard measure of phonetic quality). If you have one example of [i] with an F1 of 380, you can't say anything about "similar" and "different". Suppose you have two examples of [i], and in the second, you have F1 of 401. Does that mean these are "different vowels"? No, it means that F1 can vary. So you have to have enough examples of [i] that you can say "[i] is about here" and enough examples of [e] that you can say that "[e] is there: and those are different numbers". With 5 each, you might be able to say that those numbers are "statistically different".

In dealing with multiple speakers, the sky's sort of the limit. Suppose that you have data from speakers originally from Fiji, Capetown and Uttara Pradesh, and you wonder if that influences pronunciation – then you would want 5 speakers from each dialect. Or maybe you think it's men versus women – 5 men, 5 women. Or maybe it's a complex interaction between location and gender – 30 speakers total. More could be better, and fewer could be acceptable, but for example if you have 1 male Fijian and 1 UP female speaker, you can't validly say anything beyond "some speakers do one thing, others do something else".

There is a mindless answer that you can get online: 1067, regardless of the complexity of the question. What I'm telling you is about empirical reliability in linguistic research, not a theory of statistics (there is a stats SE for such questions, if you care). If you're generally fluent in statistics, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is for you. But otherwise, you may have communication problems: these can be minimized if you can state a specific hypothesis that you want to test (e.g. "Male speakers of Hindi are closer to both male and female RP speakers in production of [i], than female speakers of Hindi are". Since you ask what F1 is, it's not at all clear what your question about Hindi speakers would be. (I mean that kindly: if you don't know what F1 is, then before asking "how much data do I need", you need to clarify what question you are asking.

Comment: let me know  what do you mean by 'AM' and 'F1'?

Comment: I think the guys who mindlessly answer 1067 are just as clueless about statistics as they are about linguistics :P It's only suitable for one particular type of question, at one particular confidence level...

Comment: @magnum: I think you need to brush up on the basics before proceeding. Ladefoged's *Elements of Acoustic Phonetics* is an accessible intro (and a quick read) you might be interested in.

Comment: @WavesWashSands thanks for the suggestion. i shall read the book that you have recommended. hope i'll get my answer there.